# Trouble with infinite for - repeat loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, infinite-loop, repeat

I have generated an infinite loop and don't know how to fix it.

I essentially want to go through the data frame `rnumbers` and generate `rstate2` with 1, -1, or 0 depending on what is in `rnumbers`

The function `step_generator` is getting stuck at the `repeat` function. I am not sure how to make the code put -1 in `rstate2` if `rnumber` is less than C and then repeat an `ifelse` function for the next rows until a value of D or greater is obtained. Once D is obtained exit the `repeat` function and go back into the original `for` loop.

Here is my code:

```
rnumbers <- data.frame(replicate(5,runif(20000, 0, 1)))
dt <- c(.01)
A <- .01
B <- .0025
C <- .0003
D <- .003
E <- .05


rstate <- rnumbers  # copy the structure
rstate[] <- NA      # preserve structure with NA's
# Init:
rstate[1, ] <- c(0)

step_generator <- function(col, rnum){
    for (i in 2:length(col) ){
            if( rnum[i] < C) {
                col[i] <- -1
                repeat {
                    ifelse(rnum[i] < E, -1, if(rnum[i] >= D) {break})
                }
            }
                       else { if (rnum[i] < B) {col[i] <- -1 }
                              else {ifelse(rnum[i] < A, 1, 0) } }
                        }
    return(col)
    }

#  Run for each column index:
for(cl in 1:5){ rstate[ , cl] <- 
                        step_generator(rstate[,cl], rnumbers[,cl]) }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `ifelse` is not a programming control. I'm guessing the problem occurs here: `ifelse(rnum[i] < E, -1, if(rnum[i] >= D) {break})` . I have not looked at the logic of your code but perhaps substituting `if(cond){cons}else{alt}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not increasing `i` inside `repeat` loop, so basically you are testing the same `i` all the time, and because `rnum[i] < C` (from `if` condition) it will always be `rnum[i] < E` since `C < E`, and loop never breaks. 
However, if you increase `i` inside `repeat` it still will come back to value resulting from `for` loop, so you have to do it in different way, for example using `while` loop. I'm not exactly sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but basing on your description I've made this function:

```
step_generator <- function(col, rnum){
    i <- 2
    while (i <= length(col)){
        if (rnum[i] < C) {
            col[i] <- -1
            while ((i < length(col)) & (rnum[i + 1] < D)){
                i <- i + 1
                col[i] <- -1
            }
        } else if (rnum[i] < B){
            col[i] <- -1
        } else if (rnum[i] < A){
            col[i] <- 1
        } else {
            col [i] <- 0
        }
        i <- i + 1
        }
    return(col)
}
```